# Can I have Boone kill anyone other than Jeannie or Manny?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm playing an evil character, and I'm having some trouble keeping him evil. (I'm also having trouble getting him to very evil, but that's a discussion for another day.)

So I'd like to help Boone feel better about his wife (["One for My Baby"](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/One_for_My_Baby)), but I don't want him to kill Jeannie, since she's actually responsible. I don't *really* want him to kill Manny, either, since that will have no karma impact.

I'm thinking of trying to get him to whack one of my companions. Or anyone else who might be considered "good." Is this possible, or are Jeannie and Manny really my only options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have Boone kill anyone in Novac. Recruiting him if you can't prove that the person you accused was actually responsible -  either with Jeannie's documents in her case, or a fairly difficult speech check, is another matter entirely.

Keep in mind, you don't gain much Karma for accusing the right person anyway, and there are some *much* more evil options waiting for you if you don't alienate Boone right off the bat...

Comment: But no one seems to show the appropriate options yet ... Wouldn't mind whacking No-Bark, but he seems to have decent caps and be a rotten Caravan player ... A combination I really like. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have Boone kill every "named" NPC in Novac, as far as i kept trying (killing  Jeannie, Manny, No-Bark, Dino-Shop Merchant - Forgot the name) you do not gain Karma at all within this quest.

After receiving the quest from Boone, the NPCs in Novak have the Dialog Option : "Would you come to the Dino, i want to show you something" Then they will walk in front of the Dino.. the rest is up to you ;)